# Why is the 1uF capacitor needed in this load-sharing circuit?

Tags: capacitor, battery-charging

Consider the following circuit that describes a MCP73831 battery charger with a load sharing circuit:

[image]

Why is the 1uF capacitor needed? I realize that the 4.7uF are there to reduce "noise", but why the 1uF? Why this value in particular? Why would I decide such thing in my circuit and how would I come up to this value?

P.S.: Could it be to attenuate the switching time of the MOSFET when the USB is disconnected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you got the circuit from http://blog.zakkemble.co.uk/a-lithium-battery-charger-with-load-sharing/ you will note that the article specifically states that only 3 components need to be added to the basic charge circuit: Q1, D1, and R2. The article further states,

> C3 is an extra decoupling/bypass capacitor.

Since C3 is not necessary, it was presumably added as an afterthought, and the value was probably picked as a convenient number.